VizFrame SelectData Returns Null
Im generally new to UI5 and I am using version 1.71.
I've been implementing a VizFrame Bullet Chart in order to show data about different accounts.
Im trying to get the category data I click on so I've implemented the "SelectData" functionality available to VizFrame. The problem is that whenever I try to print that information, Im getting null for the outputs as seen in the console.log().
What am I missing in order to retrieve the information in the VizFrame Chart and not just null?
XML Code:
<l:BlockLayoutRow>
                    <l:BlockLayoutCell width="100">
                        <commons:ChartContainer showZoom="false">
                            <commons:ChartContainerContent title="Bar Chart">
                                <commons:content>
                                    <viz:VizFrame id="oVizFrame" selectData="onClickEventVizFrame" busy="false" busyIndicatorDelay="1000" visible="true"
                                        uiConfig="{ 'applicationSet': 'fiori' }" vizType="bullet" legendVisible="false"
                                        vizProperties="{ valueAxis: { title: { visible: false, text: 'Vertical Info' } }, title: { visible: true, text: 'Accounts for Total Payroll' }, plotArea: { colorPalette: ['#00b482'] } }">
                                        <viz:dataset>
                                            <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{oVizFrame>/book}">
                                                <viz.data:dimensions>
                                                    <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Item Category" value="{oVizFrame>ItemCategory}"/>
                                                </viz.data:dimensions>
                                                <viz.data:measures>
                                                    <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Profit" value="{oVizFrame>Profit}"/>
                                                    <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Target Profit" value="{oVizFrame>TargetProfit}"/>
                                                </viz.data:measures>
                                            </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
                                        </viz:dataset>
                                        <viz:feeds>
                                            <viz.feeds:FeedItem id="actualItem" uid="actualValues" type="Measure" values="Profit"/>
                                            <viz.feeds:FeedItem id="categoryItem" uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension" values="Item Category"/>
                                            <viz.feeds:FeedItem id="feedTargetValues" uid="targetValues" type="Measure" values="Target Profit"/>
                                        </viz:feeds>
                                    </viz:VizFrame>
                                </commons:content>
                            </commons:ChartContainerContent>
                        </commons:ChartContainer>
                    </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                </l:BlockLayoutRow>

Controller:
return BaseController.extend("thd.com.bw.YBW_UI_PL_TOOLBOX.controller.Payroll", {

        formatter: formatter,

        /* =========================================================== */
        /* lifecycle methods                                           */
        /* =========================================================== */

        onInit: function () {

            // Model used to manipulate control states. The chosen values make sure,
            // detail page is busy indication immediately so there is no break in
            // between the busy indication for loading the view's meta data
            var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
                busy: false,
                delay: 0
            });

            this.getRouter().getRoute("payroll").attachPatternMatched(this._onPayrollMatched, this);
            this.setModel(oViewModel, "payrollView");
            this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().metadataLoaded().then(this._onMetadataLoaded.bind(this));
            this._oODataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
            this._oResourceBundle = this.getResourceBundle();

            this.onReadTableData();
            this.onReadVizFrameData();
            this.onClickEventVizFrame();

        },

        onReadVizFrameData: function () {
            var oData = {
                book: [{
                    "City": "New York",
                    "ItemCategory": "Management Payroll",
                    "Profit": 10500,
                    "TargetProfit": -1000
                }, {
                    "City": "Chicago",
                    "ItemCategory": "Workers Comp",
                    "Profit": -140874.81,
                    "TargetProfit": -170000
                }, {
                    "City": "Boston",
                    "ItemCategory": "Hourly Payroll",
                    "Profit": -56994.34,
                    "TargetProfit": -75000
                }, {
                    "City": "Dallas",
                    "ItemCategory": "Total Payroll",
                    "Profit": -273793.31,
                    "TargetProfit": -280000
                }]
            };

            var oVizFrameModel = new JSONModel();

            oVizFrameModel.setData(oData);

            console.log(oVizFrameModel);

            this.setModel(oVizFrameModel, "oVizFrame");

        },
        
        onClickEventVizFrame: function (oControlEvent) {

            //var clickedData = oControlEvent.getParameter('data');

            console.log(oControlEvent);

            

        },

Screenshot of Output:
enter image description here
Things Ive tried:
Clicking the graph resulted in null when console.log()'d, tried instantiating it globally and still not working. Tried making it the only chart on the page in case of "this" giving wrong context, still did not work.
Thank you
Edit: Here is my screen when I click on the bar. We see in the log that my "selectData" event handler fires when clicking the bar in the chart, but that the parameters are null. screenshot

You are explicitly calling the event handler in the onInit. You don't need to do that.
SAPUI5 will call the onClickEventVizFrame for you automatically when you click on a bar/column/area of your chart.
When SAPUI5 calls your event handler, it also passes an object of type sap.ui.base.Event' as an argument which you are calling it the oControlEvent. In this case yes, you will be able to read any parameters from this call like data.
In other words, just remove it from your onInit
this.onClickEventVizFrame();

If you ever need to trigger an event explicitly (which is not the same as calling an event handler), you can use any fire[event name method]
So, the VizFrame class has the fireSelectData method as it has the selectData event. But again, you should not need to call fire methods in normal scenarios.

Hi @fabiopagoti, I've removed the specified line and, when I try to console log the oControlEvent from onClickEventVizFrame, my mParameters and oSouce values are still null. How can I get the category information that I click on?

is the event handler called when you click on the chart? Where in the chart are you clicking?

I am clicking on the VizFrame Bars inside the chart, I am using the Bullet variant if that changes anything. The event handler is called when I click on the chart. It pops up in the console but the necessary ones are null. Adding an edit to my post to show my screen and what I receive.

That's odd... which SAUI5 version are you using (including patch) 1.71.?

Version 1.71.69 I believe
